# What is the intuition behind *c-concavity*?

Tags: convex-analysis, definition, intuition

In a book that I’m reading, the following definition is given:

Let $c:X\times Y\to \mathbb R$ be a cost function. One says that a function $f:X\to \mathbb R$ is *c-concave* if there exists a function $g:Y\to\mathbb R$ such that $f= g^c$, where

$$ g^c(x)= \inf_y c(x,y) - g(y)$$

Can someone help me out with the intuition regarding this definition? Perhaps giving an example of functions that are *c-concave* and that are not.

Comment: $g^*(x)=-\inf_y (g(y)-xy)$ is called the Legendre transform of $g$ or its [convex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate). There is a theorem saying that convex conjugate of any function is convex, and any convex function is the convex conjugate of its convex conjugate. So convex functions are exactly the possible conjugates. This can be reformulated in terms of concave conjugates, and your definition simply replaces $c(x,y)=xy$ with general $c$. It is not meant to be intuitive, but rather to generalize the neat calculus of conjugates.

Comment: "any convex function is the convex conjugate of its convex conjugate", only if the original function is closed